# GUI Beta 2 error on login: std::bad_alloc -

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

[image]

I got the GUI BETA 1 and get this error message while trying to login on my wallet. How do I upgrade to BETA 2 safely and what shall I backup? I have my seedwords but I figure out that I could switch to another PC but my other PC has non-ascii letters in its path file so the wallet refuse to generate keys buts thats another problem.

Answer (score 2):

Locate your wallet files, there should be 3 files with the name of your wallet:

- `YourWallet.address.txt` (This is not important, just the address written inside)
- `YourWallet.keys` (This is the main thing to back-up, it holds your keys encrypted with your password - if you lose it you will need to restore from your seed words to make a new file; if you lose both this file and the seed your funds can't be recovered)
- `YourWallet` (This holds wallet refresh data, and your TX history. If you need the history, keep a backup. You're probably getting the error because of compatibility of this file between GUI versions)

Rename the last one to `YourWallet.backup` and try to start the GUI again. You will have to wait for it to refresh the wallet, shouldn't take too long since you're already synced with the network.

Comment: Where can I find these files on MAC OSX? I cant manage to find them

Answer (score 1):

Download Beta2 and extract normally. GUI Beta2 stores wallet files outside the GUI directory in a file called "Monero/wallets." I don't remember if GUI Beat1 did so also. If not, they are probably in your GUI BETA1 dir. IF that's the case you can copy the ".keys" file to the new place where GUI BETA2 stores wallets in your ~/home/Monero/wallets dir. These paths are for linux so it should be something similar for Mac.

If this is too complex, you can just restore your wallet with your seed in the new GUI when it starts up. If you have already made a wallet and it asks you for a password when it starts up, just hit "cancel" and it will take you to a screen where you can restore or create a new wallet. Keep in mind that when you restore a wallet, it will ask you to create a new password.